# Decorator - changing variable name

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am learning the concepts of decorators in Python. While I think I have covered lots of blogs and have got some basic understanding how decorators work and why would we need one.

While doing so, I encountered a tutorial (totally lost the reference to this), where while explaining about decorators, the author wrote the following:

```
def call_counter(func):
    def helper(x):          
        helper.calls += 1
        return func(x)
    helper.calls = 0
    return helper

def succ(x):
    return x + 1

succ = call_counter(succ)
print(succ.calls)
for i in range(10):
    succ(i)
print(succ.calls)
```

Output:

```
0
10
```

As I mentioned earlier, I thought I understand how a decorator works and basic Python but suddenly am doubting myself here.

In helper function, the author is incrementing `helper.calls` variable by 1 (which should be, as per my previous understanding, just an ordinary variable and `helper.`  is only to show this variable is inside `helper` function), but has only defined `helper.calls` after using it here , towards the end.

Similarly, towards end, after calling the decorator function, the author has suddenly used `succ.calls` variable - which is even printing expected result - but without any definition anywhere.

P.S. I have tried doing my research but could not even put this behaviour in proper words to find anything appropriate.

P.P.S. Could not come up with a more precise header as totally unfamiliar with the actual phenomenon happening.

Comment: Your indenting is broken, and I see no decorators...

Comment: The variable gets defined by the line `helper.calls = 0` inside `call_counter()`.  This nested function `helper` is returned by `call_counter()` and gets assigned to the global variable `succ`, so `succ.calls` now refers to the same variable as `helper.calls`.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks Jason. Though , helper.calls = 0 is defined later in the code, while I am entering into the helper function before the definition of helper.calls. I should have mentioned this confusoin explicitly in my question. Also, can you please guide bit more on global variable succ and how the name of helper.calls tansferred to a brand new variable succ.calls. Does this type of assignment has a name- for my further learning.

Comment: `call_counter()` defines `helper()` (but does not call it), adds the `calls` attribute to it, then returns it.  Top-level code then assigns that return value to `succ`.  Since `helper` and `succ` are two names for the same object, `helper.calls` and `succ.calls` are likewise two names for the same thing - there is no further assignment being made here.

Comment: Thanks @jasonharper that explains it all. It is underlying the basics of decorators or nested functions, which I thought I had covered but missed the concept that not only function name is poinitng to same piece but the functionname.attribute will also point to same thing in wrapper function.

Answer (score 1):

```
succ = call_counter(succ)  # succ.calls = 0 when function is called (succ = helper)
print(succ.calls)  # prints 0
for i in range(10):
    succ(i)  # As succ = helper now, this becomes helper(i) and helper.i is incremented by 1 each iteration, succ(x) is then returned after as func = succ and x + 1 is returned from succ(x)
print(succ.calls)  # prints 10 as helper.calls is incremented 10 times within the loop
```

The same output would have been achieved if succ(x) had returned no value as it was not used anywhere else, you can see your code visualized on http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit